# Mousemove detect left click not firing in usercontrol winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I know this should be simple to do but for some reason I can't get a simple mousemove when I left click the mouse.  this inside a custom button I have made with 2 labels in it.  I am moving only on the button area and not the label.  When I move over the button I see "Mousemove" printed to the console but when I hold the left click I get nothing...Not even the "Mousemove". I looking to implement a dragdrop for this button and was just starting out simple to detect the left click and mousemove.  Am I missing another setting.  I had a Click event and event removed that just to detect this movement.
Thanks in advance for any info.

```
Public Sub New()
    'InitializeComponent()
    DoubleBuffered = True
    AllowDrop = True

End Sub

Private Sub CustomerButton_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    Debug.Print("MouseMove")
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Debug.Print("MouseMove and Left Click")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you click outside your Button Control, then hold the left Mouse Button while moving the pointer over the Button Control, you get no MouseMove events, the Mouse is already captured by the Control where the click event was first generated. -- BTW, it's not exactly clear what kind of functionality you're trying to implement here. Should the Button Control start a DragDrop operation (i.e., is it the Source or the Target)? How is the UserControl involved (since it has `AllowDrop = True`)?

Comment: I am trying to implement a drag and drop on a custom button I made.  I tried what you said and I still don't get the "MouseMove and Left Click".  I have drag and drops working for datagridviews in my app but I can't get this working.

Comment: I didn't suggest to do anything, I just described what *might* cause the current behavior. -- You have to clarify what the Button's role is in this. Since you're handling the `MouseMove` event, it appears the Button should initiate the DragDrop operation (so it's the Source). But it also looks like the UC itself is the Target (since you have set `AllowDrop = True`) -- If you position the Mouse Pointer over the UC's Button, hold the Left Mouse Button and you drag the Pointer, then the `If` condition is met. Not in case the Mouse Left Button is pressed outside the UC's Button.